# Mongo DB Compass and Filtering on int 64

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Below is an image of a single record in my mongo database.  I am using mongodb compass and if I search with the term

{date: 1567532362460}

I find my record.  If however I search with terms like:

{key: 6366627898639550262} or {user: -6302170947335878914}

Then are no records found.  At first I thought it was a format issue except compass will auto complete everything so I assume this because these are int64's and there is a rounding error.  How do I search on these fields with compass?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If filter accepts extended json syntax, use `{key:{$numberLong:"1234..."}}` to  specify long values.

Comment: This results in error: unknown operator: $numberLong

Comment: got it the proper format is {key:NumberLong("6366627898639550262")}